# Return String from Server PHP File to Client Web Page

Tags: php

There's lots on this but I can't find anything that specifically works in my case. The following are two test files PHP and HTML. The HTML file simply has two text boxes with a button each. I would like the following to occur:

1. The upper textbox data to be sent to the PHP file when the 'Send' button is clicked. *This works!*
2. The PHP file then opens a text file and appends the data. *This works!*
3. On clicking the 'Receive' button, the PHP file opens the text file and reads the data. *This works!*
4. Now I'm stumped. How do I get the data back from the PHP file to the lower textbox in the in the HTML file?

Note: I'm using the `jquery.redirect` plugin for transferring data.

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src='jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>
    <script src="jquery.redirect.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='send' type='text'></input>
    <div id='btnSend'><center>Send</center></div>
    <input id='receive' type='text'></input>
    <div id='btnReceive'><center>Receive</center></div>

<style>
#btnSend {
    width: 60px;
    border: solid 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#btnReceive {
    width: 60px;
    border: solid 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#btnSend').click(function(){
        var dataOut = $('#send').val();
        $.redirect('http://troncon.ca/ESO/test.php',{ userOut: dataOut});
    });
    $('#btnReceive').click(function(){
        $.redirect('http://troncon.ca/ESO/test.php',{ userIn: ''});
    });

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['userOut'])) {
    sendData();
}
elseif(isset($_POST['userIn'])) {
    getData();
}

function sendData() {
    $handle = fopen('test.txt', "a");
    $test = $_POST['userOut'];
    fwrite($handle, $test);
    fclose($handle);
}

function getData() {
    $filename = "test.txt";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    //echo $contents;
}
?>
```

Comment: You should consider using Ajax so you're expecting a result back after sending the data.

Comment: The redirect pluging you are using does not receive data, only sends. You probably have to use other method like `$.post('http://troncon.ca/ESO/test.php',{userOut: dataOut},function(data){alert(data)});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO the data fetch and send using AJAX:

An example based on your code would be:

```
$('#btnSend').click(function() {
    var dataOut = $('#send');
    var data = {
        userOut: dataOut.val()
    };
    $.post("http://troncon.ca/ESO/test.php", data, function(data, status) {
        alert("Data saved ");
    });
});
$('#btnReceive').click(function() {
    var dataIn = $('#receive');
    var data = {
        userIn: ''
    };
    $.post("http://troncon.ca/ESO/test.php", data, function(data, status) {
        dataIn.val(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replies. When I use Iceman's code the send part works fine. The receive though gives me an error "data is not defined". I assume I need to do something with the PHP file but not sure what. Can you point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: @TedN uncomment the `echo $contents` in ur php

Comment: Nope. I had already un-commented it when I was getting the error. My understanding of Ajax is minimal. How does "data" get populated with the string ($contents) in my current PHP code?

Comment: your function just reads the contents from the file - `fread`

Comment: @very sorry typo, corrected!!! hadn't initialised the data parameter in the receive

Comment: OK. Thank you very much Iceman. Everything works good now : ) I don't think I'm allowed to add votes, hopefully someone else will oblige.